# Python suppress warnings messages in console logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, suppress-warnings

I have a python program that when I run works as expected but there is this annoying statement that spams my console logs.

`W0131 18:09:51.881016  2064 default_variables.cpp:91] Fail to fscanf: Success [0]`

I am not sure where is this coming from and I tried looking for solutions to suppress this but couldn't find a relevant solution.

I tried using python warnings package but it is not working in this case.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

I also tried these but they didn't work here.

```
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"
```

and

```
python -W ignore my_script.py
```

It looks like someone else also has faced this issue: https://github.com/typesense/typesense/issues/208 but the issue is closed without a proper solution.

**Update: Running the script through VS Code Debugger somehow suppresses this warning statement (doesn't let it get printed on the console). How is VS Code able to suppress this?**

Answer (score 1):

```py
python -W ignore test.py
```

Use `-W ignore` flag.

There is also the option to use a env var:

```sh
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Forgot to add to my question but I had tried these as well along with trying the `warnings` package. Have edited my question content.

Comment: Okay maybe it is not a „warning“ then but something else? Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yeah could be, it might be coming from one of the packages used in the program but the fact that it doesn't cause any errors makes it look like some sort of warning.